# Unable to properly parse a string via character modification

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I'm running into an issue where my Python code is not correctly returning a function call designed to add an underscore character before each capital letter and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. For an output, only the "courseID" word in the string is getting touched whereas the other two words are not.

I thought cycling thru the letters in a word, looking for capitalized letters would work, but it doesn't appear to be so. Could someone let me know where my code might be going wrong?

```
def parse_variables(string):
    new_string=''
    for letter in string:
        if letter.isupper():
            pos=string.index(letter)
            parsed_string=string[:pos] + '_' + string[pos:]
            new_string=''.join(parsed_string+letter)
        else:
            new_string=''.join(letter)
#        new_string=''.join(letter)
    return new_string.lower()

parse_variables("courseID pathID apiID")
```

Current output is a single letter lowercase `d` and the expected output should be `course_id path_id api_id`.

Comment: Please show what you get when running this code, and what you expect to get instead.

Comment: @mkrieger1, I would like to get something like this: 'course_id, path_id, api_id'. I updated my code a bit because I realized I probably should be having an else statement with my if to store the letters I'm modifying.

Comment: So what *exactly* do you want to get? With or without commas? Converting everything to lower case? And what *do* you get instead?

Comment: I updated my original description with current and expected outcomes

Comment: What are you going to do with `parsed_string`? It is never used.

Comment: That was a mistake on my part. It should be joined to the new_string variable during the 'if' statement call if the current letter is uppercase. Please see the description update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your revised code is that `index` only finds the first occurence of the capital letter in the string. Since you have repeated instances of the same capital letters, the function never finds the subsequent instances. You could simplify your approach and avoid this issue by simply concatenating the letters with or without underscores depending on whether they are uppercase as you iterate.

For example:

```
def underscore_caps(s):
    result = ''
    for c in s:
        if c.isupper():
            result += f'_{c.lower()}'
        else:
            result += c

    return result

print(underscore_caps('courseID pathID apiID'))
# course_i_d path_i_d api_i_d
```

Or a bit more concisely using list comprehension and `join`:

```
def underscore_caps(s):
    return ''.join([f'_{c.lower()}' if c.isupper() else c for c in s])

print(underscore_caps('courseID pathID apiID'))
# course_i_d path_i_d api_i_d
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of issues with your code:

1. `string.index(letter)` gives the index of the **first** occurrence of `letter`, so if you have multiple e.g. `D`, `pos` will only update to the position of the first one.
   You could correct this by iterating over both position and letter using `enumerate` e.g. `for pos, letter in enumerate(string):`
2. You are putting underscores before **each** capital letter i.e. `_i_d`
3. You are overwriting previous edits by referring to `string` in `parsed_string=string[:pos] + '_' + string[pos:]`

Correcting all these issues you would have:

```
def parse_variables(string):
    new_string=''
    for pos, letter in enumerate(string):
        if letter.isupper() and pos+1 < len(string) and string[pos+1].isupper():
            new_string += f'_{letter}'
        else:
            new_string += letter
    return new_string.lower()
```

But a much simpler method is:

```
"courseID pathID apiID".replace('ID', '_id')
```

---

**Update:**

Given the variety of strings you want to capture, it seems regex is the tool you want to use:

```
import re

def parse_variables(string, pattern=r'(?<=[a-z])([A-Z]+)', prefix='_'):
    """Replace patterns in string with prefixed lowercase version.
    Default pattern is any substring of consecutive
    capital letters that occur after a lowercase letter."""

    foo = lambda pat: f'{prefix}{pat.group(1).lower()}'
    return re.sub(pattern, foo, text)
```

```
text = 'courseID pathProjects apiCode'
parse_variables(text)

>>> course_id path_projects api_code
```

Comment: Thanks Ukemi, I'd go with the latter, but sometimes the 'ID' gets changed into something else, so it becomes less predictable for a simpler replace to work here.

Comment: @xorLogic can you provide a list of the different things 'ID' can get changed to? This sounds like a problem for regex.

Comment: Sure, so it can change from 'ID' to things like 'Code', ''Projects", etc... no real rhyme or reason

Comment: @xorLogic I've added a regex solution for the updated problem.

Comment: Thanks Ukemi. The bigger issue is that I'm working with delimiters so I may have to chance my entire approach. Still, being able to work around without using regex here is ideal.

Answer (score 1):

I think a regex solution would be easier to understand here.  This takes words that end with capital letters and adds the underscore and makes them lowercase

```
import re

s = "courseID pathID apiID exampleABC DEF"

def underscore_lower(match):
    return "_" + match.group(1).lower()

pat = re.compile(r'(?<=[^A-Z\s])([A-Z]+)\b')

print(pat.sub(underscore_lower, s))
# course_id path_id api_id example_abc DEF
```

You might have to play with that regex to get it to do exactly what you want.  At the moment, it takes capital letters at the end of words that are preceded by a character that is neither a capital letter or a space.  It then makes those letters lowercase and adds an underscore in front of them.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I think in this instance, I was more or less looking for something that could run thru all the characters in a word. I'm trying to avoid regex as much as possible since I know how finneky it can get.